# How to display a Gyfcat iframe in an Android WebView

Tags: android, html, kotlin, iframe, webview

So I am trying to display a gif that I am pulling from reddit in a webview in my app. From the reddit api I retrieve a JSON of a posts data, and from `media_embed/content` I get the html of an iFrame from Gyfcat that looks like this:

```
&lt;iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fifr%2Fhalffeistyharlequinbug&amp;display_name=Gfycat&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fhalffeistyharlequinbug&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fthumbs.gfycat.com%2FHalfFeistyHarlequinbug-size_restricted.gif&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=gfycat" width="600" height="600" scrolling="no" title="Gfycat embed" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="true"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

To this I URLDecode it like so:

```
val gifData = json["media_embed"]["content"]
val decoded = URLDecoder.decode(gifData, "UTF-8")
```

And I display it like so:

```
feedItemWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
feedItemWebView.loadData(decoded, "text/html", "UTF-8")
```

This gives me something that looks like this:[image: bad WebView1]

Instead of using URLDecoder I also tried doing this:

```
val decoded = gifData.replace("&lt;", "<")
                      .replace("&gt;", ">")
                      .replace("&amp;", "&")
```

And putting this in the WebView in the same way as above results in the webview loading, but just displaying a still image (and not the gif as expected) like this:

[image]

Is there something I am missing that I need to do in order for it to actually play the gif?

If I try putting the same thing into an html file like this:

```html
<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fifr%2Fhalffeistyharlequinbug&amp;display_name=Gfycat&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fhalffeistyharlequinbug&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fthumbs.gfycat.com%2FHalfFeistyHarlequinbug-size_restricted.gif&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=gfycat" width="600" height="600" scrolling="no" title="Gfycat embed" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

my browser will load it correctly, so it must be something wrong with the WebView or my WebView settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming from a wrong configuration of the WebView. In fact, reading the logcat, this information came out from the webview:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(26)] "Error reading storage", source: https://gfycat.com/assets/app.bfa24b4d87267ff469b0.js (26)
```

The iframe is loading an external script which use [html5_webstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) also called localStorage. It is disabled by default in the webview (Security reason), so trying to access it was throwing an error which was preventing the video to play.

Therefore we need to turn it on like follow:

```
String data = "<iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fifr%2Fhalffeistyharlequinbug&amp;display_name=Gfycat&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fhalffeistyharlequinbug&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fthumbs.gfycat.com%2FHalfFeistyHarlequinbug-size_restricted.gif&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=gfycat\" width=\"600\" height=\"600\" scrolling=\"no\" title=\"Gfycat embed\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></iframe>\n";

webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);

webview.loadData(data, "text/html", null);
```

I tested it on a really simple project considering you already got the iFrame html.